# Clustering an array of values without using thresholds

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I want to segment A 1D dataset where each value represents an error into 2 segments:

- A cluster with the smallest values
- All the others

Example:

```
X = np.array([1, 1.5, 0.4, 1.1, 23, 24, 22.5, 21, 20, 25, 40, 50, 50, 51, 52, 53]).reshape(-1, 1)
```

In this small example, I would like to regroup the 4 first values in a cluster and forget about the others. **I do not want a solution based on a threshold. The point is that the cluster of interest centroid will not always have the same value. It might be `1e-6`, or it might be `1e-3`, or it might be `1`.**

My idea was to use a k-means clustering algorithm, which would work fine if I did know how many clusters existed in my data. In the example above, the number is 3, one around 1 (the cluster of interest), one around 22, and one around 51. But sadly, I do not know the number of clusters... Simply searching for 2 clusters will not lead to a segmentation of the dataset as intended.

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(X)
kmeans.labels_
```

Returns a cluster 1 way too large, which also includes the data from the cluster centered around 22.

```
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

I did find some interesting answers on methods to select the k, but it complexifies the algorithm and I feel like there must be a far better way to solve this problem.

I'm open to any suggestions and example which could work on the `X` array provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find [`AffinityPropagation`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#affinity-propagation) useful here, as it does not require to specify the amount of clusters to generate. You might have to tune however the `damping factor` and `preference`, so that it produces the expected results.

On the provided example, the default parameters seem to do the job:

```
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation

X = np.array([1, 1.5, 0.4, 1.1, 23, 24, 22.5, 
              21, 20, 25, 40, 50, 50, 51, 52, 53]).reshape(-1, 1)
ap = AffinityPropagation(random_state=12).fit(X)
y = ap.predict(X)
print(y)
# array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int64)
```

To obtain individual clusters from `X`, you can index using `y`:

```
first_cluster = X[y==0].ravel()
first_cluster
# array([1. , 1.5, 0.4, 1.1])
second_cluster = X[y==1].ravel()
second_cluster
# array([23. , 24. , 22.5, 21. , 20. , 25. ])
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks very promising. Looking into it!